# How can I change text file encoding?

Tags: node.js, encoding

I want to change file encoding utf-8 -> euc-kr.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) tool:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t euc-kr file
```

There is a node.js library at https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv that might help you without resorting to external tools.